# Cannot connect jdbc to sql server

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc

Below is my code for a simple select query for the Sql Server using jdbc.

```
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
public class DateServer{
public void dbconnect(String conn, String user, String pass){
    try{
        Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(conn, user, pass);
        System.out.println("connected");
        Statement stat = con.createStatement();
        String query = "select * from headcount_new";
        ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery(query);                      
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}    
public static void main(String[] args){
    DateServer conserver = new DateServer();
    conserver.dbconnect("jdbc:sqlserver://&lt;<hostname>&gt", "&lt;<username>&gt", "&lt;<password>&gt");        
}
}
```

I am getting the following error:

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The connection string contains a badly                   formed name or value.
    at  com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:171)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.Util.parseUrl(Util.java:420)
    at    com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.parseAndMergeProperties(SQLServerDriver.java:856)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:838)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
    at DateServer.dbconnect(DateServer.java:9)
    at DateServer.main(DateServer.java:22)"
```

Can someone please help me what the error is about? I am new to Java.

thanks.

Comment: rolled back to original question: OP should ask another

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why you have `&lt;<hostname>&gt` etc

A JDBC URL looks like this

```
   jdbc:sqlserver://SomeServer;user=SomeUser;password=XXX;
```

Comment: @ghbhatt: that is a new question then. YOu should accept may answer if you like it and ask a new one that is specfic to the new problem I will rollback your update

Answer (score 2):

this has nothing to do with java.  in your connection string you have to replace '<hostname>', '<username>', etc. with actual values.  See here for valid syntax: http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0340__Database/AListofJDBCDriversconnectionstringdrivername.htm